# Is it correct way of saying that a moving electric field causes magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

$$\mathbf B=\mathbf V \times \mathbf E \mu _0 \epsilon _0$$

$\mathbf V$ is the velocity vector of moving electric field. Rest of the parameters follow usual notations for those.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **fields don't move** because fields are everywhere in space. For example temperature is a field that has a value at every point in space and all the time, but when the sources moves, the field changes.

So, I suppose you mean by "moving electric field" that the electric field change with respect to time in a way that the values become shifted by $\mathbf{v} dt$ for a time interval $dt$. Electric and magnetic fields can change over time according to some situations, like changing sources such as moving charges or alternating currents. However, electric and magnetic fields do not change each other. I will explain how you get the relation in your question at the end of the answer but first I need to clarify some important points.

### Electromagnetic Potentials

As a matter of fact, **there is no cause-and-effect relation between electric and magnetic fields**. Rather they both caused by more fundamental fields, called electromagnetic potentials, one is scalar and denoted by $\phi (\mathbf{r},t)$, and the other is vector and denoted by $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$. Their derivatives define how the electric and magnetic field will correlate, as follows:
\begin{align}
\tag{1.a}
\mathbf{E} & \equiv - \mathbf{\nabla} \phi - \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t} \\
\tag{1.b}
\mathbf{B} & \equiv \mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{A}
\end{align}
So, counting the degrees of freedom, $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ have 6 in total but they can be derived from 4. The reason why Maxwell, Faraday and Ampére didn't start from them is because they were perceived by forces.

### Maxwell's Equations for Potential Fields

The electric and magnetic fields correlate according to the potentials, and those potentials change with respect to the Maxwell's equations which become as follows, in this *potential formulation*:
\begin{align}
\tag{2.a}
\Box \varphi + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left ( \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}\right ) &= - \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} 
\\
\tag{2.b}
\Box  \mathbf A - \mathbf \nabla \left ( \mathbf \nabla \cdot \mathbf A + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} \right ) &= - \mu_0 \mathbf J
\end{align}
where $\Box = \nabla^2- \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$ is the d'Alembert operator, and $\rho(\mathbf r, t)$ and $\mathbf{J} (\mathbf{r}, t)$ are charge density and current density, respectively. The expression in paranthesis can be eliminated by shifting those potentials, $\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{\nabla} \chi$ and  $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi + \partial_t \chi$, with respect to a continuous scalar function, $\chi(\mathbf r, t)$, such that
\begin{align}
\tag{Lorenz gauge}
\mathbf {\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = 0
\end{align}
however, due to their definition in (1), electric and magnetic fields will remain unchanged under this shift, i.e. $\mathbf E \rightarrow \mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B \rightarrow \mathbf B$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\tag{3.a}
\Box \varphi &= - \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} 
\\
\tag{3.b}
\Box  \mathbf A  &= - \mu_0 \mathbf{J}
\end{align}

### Correlation of E&M Fields Without Sources

So, your question reduces to how these fields correlate in this way even there is no source to change the potentials. The answer becomes obvious when you write Maxwell's equations of (3) without sources, that is:
\begin{align}
\tag{4}
\Box \varphi = 0 
&& and &&
\Box  \mathbf A  = 0
\end{align}
These are just wave equations. So, if you have an antenna producing a changing $\varphi$ and $\mathbf A$, which is basically a rod that moves charges back and forth, then at really far distance, where the effects of the sources become negligible, there would still be a wave traveling to that distance. This kind of wave is called electromagnetic wave since it has both electric and magnetic components. So, EM wave is an energy transferred by the electromagnetic fields because of some source that is no longer effecting it.

### Moving Sources

One can ask *then how moving charges produce magnetic field, if the field isn't moving?* The answer is right there: moving charge means a nonzero current density which produces vector potential according to (3.b), which produces magnetic fields due to (1.b).

However, one can also obtain this result by just switching from an observer A who sees the charge is at rest to an observer B that sees the charge is moving at a velocity, $\mathbf{v}$. Observer A experiences $ \Box \varphi = -\rho / \epsilon_0$ and, say, $\mathbf{A} =0$. In order to obtain what Observer B experiences, one needs to use Lorentz transformations, because Electrodynamics is a Lorentz invariant theory. So, one needs to construct the kinematics of classical electrodynamics on the theory of Special Relativity.

Hence, Lorentz transformations of the potential fields are as follows:
\begin{align}
\varphi' &= \gamma (\varphi - \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A} ) \\
\mathbf {A}'_{||} &= \gamma (\mathbf{A} _{||} - \mathbf{v} \varphi / c^2 ) \\
\mathbf {A}'_\perp & = \mathbf{A} _\perp
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A}_{||}$ and $\mathbf {A}_\perp$ are parallel and perpendicular components of the vector potential, and $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ is the Lorentz factor.

Therefore, Observer B will have the following field values in terms of Observer A's fields according to Lorentz transformations:
\begin{align}
\varphi^B &= \gamma \varphi^A \\
\mathbf{A}^B &= -\gamma \mathbf{v} \varphi^A / c^2
\end{align}
which gives a nonzero magnetic field as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}^B &= \nabla \times \mathbf{A}^B\\
&= - \frac{1}{c^2}\left( \varphi^B  \nabla \times \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{v} \times \nabla \varphi^B  \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{c^2} \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{E}^B
\end{align}
where $\mathbf v$ is constant (or at least curl-free since we only switch to inertial observers).

Comment: thanks i am much helped out with your answer. In fact by saying moving electric field i meant a moving source, an infinitely long straight line of electric charge that moves in a direction perpendicular to it's length along circumference of a circle thus producing surface current flowing in transverse direction over the surface of an infinitely long hollow cylinder.

Comment: Great answer! You said that "there is no cause-and-effect relation between electric and magnetic fields". What do you then say about what I typically hear of, "changing magnetic fields produce electric fields", and vice versa? I understand the potentials are "more fundamental", but can't you still argue there is some cause and effect between the two fields? Or is this phrase just typically used for intro physics just to help students grasp Faraday's Law, etc.?

Comment: Well, there is a historical origin to that phrase because at the time of Faraday the concept of field was already new, and it seemed they cause each other (hence the name, *induction*). In his dairy entry of Oct 17, 1831, Faraday notes that *[induction] effect was repeated every time the magnet was put in or out, and therefore a wave of Electricity was so **produced** from mere approximation of a magnet, and not from its formation in situ.*

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but this doesn't answer my question. Do you think this is correct? How do you reconcile this with what you said of "there is no cause-and-effect relation between electric and magnetic fields"?

Comment: As I have discussed in the main answer: since $\mathbf{A}$ and $\varphi$ are more fundamental and they are completely independent variables of the theory, electric and magnetic fields will not be within a cause-and-effect relation. Instead both are caused by potential fields

Comment: I don't see how the fields being determined by potentials necessarily means there is no cause-and-effect relationship between the fields. The potentials might be more mathematically fundamental, but I would argue the fields are "more physical" than the potentials.

Comment: Potentials are physically more fundamental. Of course it is more obvious in Quantum Field Theory since the vector $(\varphi,\mathbf{A})$ is directly the photon field and when you detect a photon you actually detect these potential fields not their force. But it is still physically more fundamental as well as in classical physics because the phase symmetry of nature provides EM interaction. On the other hand, the electric/magnetic field is simply *force per charge/current of EM interaction*, and in early days of EMT it was easier to formulate the theory in terms of force.

Comment: That's fine. Your answer is great. I just don't think fundamental potentials necessarily means there is no cause-and-effect relationship. I can see where you are coming from, I just don't see your reasoning. One thing can cause another thing to happen even if there are more fundamental things happening behind the scene.

Comment: I am not claiming a general rule like if two things are derived from other things they can not have a cause-and-effect relation. In general you are right. However, I am giving the particular case for electric and magnetic fields. $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields are distinct (linearly independent) components of the same thing (namely, field strength tensor, $F_{\mu\nu}$), and this thing is derived from a more fundamental object (namely, EM potential field, $A_\mu$).